# Picasa API and getting not edited photo

Tags: google-plus, picasa, google-data-api, google-photos

I use Picasa Web Albums API to get photos from the server. If i edit photo using g+ editor and save changes, i could revert my image to original by pressing button in browser. Is there any way to get not edited photo using API or any other way?